# Use Double as default instead of BigDecimal Groovy

Tags: java, groovy

I'm running Groovy scripts inside of Java using the GrooyShell. From what i've seen, Groovy uses BigDecimal as the default for calculation, i need to use Double as the default, is there any way of doing it from the GroovySheell?

I tried using the ComplierConfiguration class, but i haven't seen any option for that.

Comment: Yes groovy uses BigDecimal by default. If you want to use doubles you can put a D suffix on your numbers.